# Using PHP and LDAP to connect to Microsoft Office 365

Tags: php, authentication, ldap, office365

The company that I work for has migrated their local exchange to a hosted Office 365 solution.  We are in the process of building out several externally(to our local network) hosted websites and would like to use LDAP authentication to build upon our existing, hosted user base.

Can anyone explain or point to some documentation of a way to use PHP and LDAP to connect to a remotely hosted AD (in this case Office 365) and authenticate users to it?

Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: I would very much *hope* that the remote directory is not directly accessible across the internet. Do you have a VPN set up to the remote DC or something?

Comment: Hey Dave, I guess I didn't really make myself clear.  All of the PHP/LDAP examples I can find consist of a PHP script on the same server as the DC.  What I am interested in is using PHP/LDAP from a webhost to connect to a hosted Office 365 (hosted by Microsoft) and authenticate user credentials against that.

Comment: Yeh I'm pretty certain that's not possible. I am by no means an expert on Office 365 (quite the opposite in fact) but abstracting from that layer of it, it would be far too big a security risk for M$ to open up the LDAP server to the public internet like that. I would be *very* surprised if they allow this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible.  Microsoft has recently released a Developer Preview for their [Windows Azure](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/) cloud platform which functions like many other cloud computing services ([Amazon](http://aws.amazon.com/), [Pagoda Box](https://pagodabox.com/), [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/)).  Along with this new product is the ability for developed apps to leverage Single Sign On using your Office365 account credentials.

Here are a few articles that go over the PHP process:

1. [How to implement single sign-on with Windows Azure Active Directory - PHP Application](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/how-to-guides/web-sso/)
2. [Get Started with Windows Azure Active Directory](http://haishibai.blogspot.com/2012/07/guided-tour-of-windows-azure-active.html)

Notes:

- Example one has its source in a git repo.  This repo does not include a referenced .csproj file, so you will have to build the project with the included 3 source files.  If I can do it, you can do it :).
- It should also be noted that after Office365 authentication is complete and reroutes back to your app, it expects the return URL to be HTTPS, if it is not you will get an error (or at least I did).

Comment: above Link is 404; [link](http://www.lewisroberts.com/2015/09/04/single-sign-on-with-azure-ad-in-php/) is thorough and expands on the original

Answer (score -2):

I had done a ldap authentication and other stuff using php this is the basic authentication make sure your DN is correct when you are trying to authenticate.

```
      define("LDAPSERVER","192.168.0.1"); // your server
      define("LDAPBINDDN","cn=Worker,dc=mlonline,");
      define("LDAPBINDPW","FakePassword");


        $ds=ldap_connect(LDAPSERVER);
        if($ds){
            try{
                    $bind=ldap_bind($ds,LDAPBINDDN,LDAPBINDPW);
                    if($bind){
                            //yeah authenticated
                    }else{
                        throw new Exception('Cannot Connect to server Authentication Failed');
                    }

            }catch(Exception $e){
                throw $e;
            }
        }else{
           throw new Exception('Server Down');
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response... After looking at your example, my question would be: What should the LDAPSERVER and LDAPBINDDN variables be defined as to connect to the Office 365 server?

Comment: the LDAPSERVER is the location of your server or its address and for the LDAPBINDDN  read this http://www.ldapman.org/articles/intro_to_ldap.html as you need to know where your user is in the active directory first

Comment: @user1415567 I'm also wondering what "my server" is supposed to be. I don't have a server, I'm with Office365. There are per-account servers for mail at xyz.mail.protection.outlook.com and for the web at xyz.sharepoint.com. But it's not going to be one of those, is it?