# Logging into Office365 email using PHP

Tags: php, email, azure, single-sign-on, office365

I have an application which I would like to integrate with my company's Office365 email through a single sign on.
Here is how I was thinking of doing it:

My application can take the email address and password (or username) which users have logged into it and pass it out to a web service (in this case a PHP page).
The PHP page takes the username and password and users them to sign into Office365 email. 
The user is redirected to the email page.

We are using Office365 with a local Azure tenancy and local AD.

I have used this same methodology to integrate with Open SSO, however, I can not find any information in how to authenticate to Office365 pragmatically using PHP.

Can anyone advise how this is done / where I can look?

Thanks,

-Max

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this other post that should help you out:

[Using PHP and LDAP to connect to Microsoft Office 365](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551181/using-php-and-ldap-to-connect-to-microsoft-office-365)

--- Bob ---

Answer (score 0):

I appear to be closer to the answer. Take a look at my question here to view the code - [Sending custom HTTP request with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240060/sending-custom-http-request-with-php)

There is also a blog post by MSDN which will provide you with more information here - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2014/03/25/using-oauth2-to-access-calendar-contact-and-mail-api-in-exchange-online-in-office-365.aspx