# Sending custom HTTP request with PHP

Tags: php, office365

I am trying to authenticate with the new Office 365 API. I have successfully authenticated and I'm swimming in a garden of roses.

However, the last part is to sent a custom HTTP request with my shiny new access token. It doesn't seem to be working though.

Can someone please outline how to send the http request detailed below with PHP?

```
GET https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/OData/Me/Inbox/Messages?$top=5
User-Agent: My-Cool-WebApp/1.0
client-request-id: 9aa1c740-25e2-4841-9146-ef7018f7bf37
return-client-request-id: true
authorization: Bearer {access token your app received in Step Three}
```

Thanks

[Associated MSDN tutorial here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2014/03/25/using-oauth2-to-access-calendar-contact-and-mail-api-in-exchange-online-in-office-365.aspx)

Code Below:

```
$code = $_GET['code'];

$accessToken = AccessCode::getCode($code);

$EmailData = EmailSearch::getEmail($accessToken);


class AccessCode
{
public static function getCode($code)
{
    //
    $url = 'https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token';
    //
    $data = array('grant_type' => 'authorization_code', 'code' => $code, 'redirect_uri' => 'redirect_uri','client_id' => 'client_id','client_secret' => 'client_secret', 'resource' => '00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000');
    //
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data),
        ),
    );
    //
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    //
    $result = json_decode(file_get_contents($url, false, $context));
    //
    return $result->access_token;
}
}

class EmailSearch
{
public static function getEmail($accessToken)
{
    //
    $url = 'https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/OData/Me';

    $requestID = create_guid();

    $request_headers = array('client-request-id: '. $requestID,
                             'return-client-request-id: true',
                             "Authorization: Bearer $accessToken");
    //
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'GV-Email-Forward/1.0');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    var_dump($result);
}
}

function create_guid($namespace = '') {     
static $guid = '';
$uid = uniqid("", true);
$data = $namespace;
$data .= $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
$data .= $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$data .= $_SERVER['LOCAL_ADDR'];
$data .= $_SERVER['LOCAL_PORT'];
$data .= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$data .= $_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'];
$hash = strtoupper(hash('ripemd128', $uid . $guid . md5($data)));
$guid = '{' .   
        substr($hash,  0,  8) . 
        '-' .
        substr($hash,  8,  4) .
        '-' .
        substr($hash, 12,  4) .
        '-' .
        substr($hash, 16,  4) .
        '-' .
        substr($hash, 20, 12) .
        '}';
return $guid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cURL :

Here is a simple example :

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

You'll find the list of options you'll need there : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Answer (score 0):

You can do this quite easily with [PHP's `cURL` functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php).

For example:

```
<?php

$url = 'https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/OData/Me/Inbox/Messages?$top=5';

$request_headers = array('client-request-id: 9aa1c740-25e2-4841-9146-ef7018f7bf37',
                         'return-client-request-id: true',
                         "authorization: $my_access_token");

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'My-Cool-WebApp/1.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// Now do something with $result...
```

Make sure you use single quotes for the declaration of `$url`, otherwise `$top` will be interpreted as a reference to a PHP variable.

Comment: This seems perfect but I am getting a 401 Unauthorized response. What could be causing this?

Comment: @AndrewTurnbull Make sure you're following the [API specification](http://bit.ly/1lEMZJH) to the letter. For example, have you generated a unique GUID for `client-request-id`? (If you need a Microsoft-compatible GUID, [this function by redtraider](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php#107512) will come in useful.) By the look of things, the `authorization` header should consist of the word `Bearer`, followed by a space, followed by your (base64) access token. Perhaps it would also help if you created your own `User-Agent` value instead of using the one provided as an example.

Comment: I am using that very function to create the client-request-id for every request. The application has all of the required permissions and the User agent is "GV-Email-Forward/1.0". Would it help if I posted my code?

Comment: @AndrewTurnbull Your code looks OK. Perhaps there's a problem elsewhere. Check the code you're using to obtain user consent (step 2 in the page I linked to earlier).